# Call to virtual function cause Segmentation Fault in C++

Tags: c++, pointers, segmentation-fault, virtual-functions

I am having a problem with a simple math analysis tool I am developing in C++,
specifically the program cause Segmentation Fault at a certain point during execution. Here is a
simplified version of the code:

```
#include <string>

using namespace std;

class Function 
{

string equation;

public: 
    Function(string equation) { this->equation = equation; }
    virtual string derivative() 
    { 
        // throws exception since it 
        // should never be invoked on Function 
    }
};

class Polynomial : public Function
{

public:
    Polynomial(string equation) : Function(equation);
    string derivative() { //compute the derivative }
};

class Exponential : public Function
{

public:
    Exponential(string equation) : Function(equation);
    string derivative() { //compute the derivative }
};

...

class Logarithmic : public Function
{

public:
    Logarithmic(string equation) : Function(equation);
    string derivative() { //compute the derivative }
};

int main(int argc, char * argv)
{
    string equation = argv;
    Function *f;
    if (//some condition)
        f = new Polynomial();
    else if (//some condition)
        f = new Exponential();
    ...

    else if (//some condition)
        f = new Logarithmic();

    string der = f->derivative();
}
```

My guess is that the problem is caused by the pointer `*f`  losing the assigned value after
the if-statement (by initializing it to `Function *f = new Function();` I get an
exception instead of a SegFault, meaning that it calls the method in the parent class).
In case it may help, I am working in a QT environment on a Ubuntu 13.10 machine.
Can someone help me fix this or suggest an alternative pattern? Thanks

Comment: Compile your code with `g++ -Wall -Wextra -g`. Then use the `gdb` debugger.

Comment: Assuming that your syntactic errors in the test/assignment aren't in your real code, you don't have a final `else` exiting with an error. You leave open the possibility that all the cases fail and you try to call `derivative()` on a null or garbage pointer.

Comment: This should not even compile. *f = new Polynomial() is just bullshit and the compiler should recognize it as such and reject it.

Comment: @DeadMG Sadly, our compilers are way too (-f)permissive.

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch As I said, this is a very simplified version of my code, I'll try compiling as you suggest

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like to me that you are falling off the end of your `if-else` ladder and calling `derivative()` on a bad pointer, leading to the run-time SEGFAULT. Add a final `else` that exits with an error to verify this.

Beyond that, you should be using `f = new Polynomial();`, etc., as people elsewhere have said. I'm assuming you actually are if your source compiles.

Answer (score 1):

That:

```
Function *f;
if (//some condition)
    *f = new Polynomial();
```

Is probably causing the crash.

Should be:

```
    f = new Polynomial();
```

Comment: would that even compile? Looks like a static typing error to me.

Comment: @Jeff Unless there is a constructor or an assignment operator that accepts a `Function*`.

Comment: assuming that someone who knows those overloads would be able to spot uninitialized pointer dereference...

Comment: @Jeff There could be no correlation...

Answer (score 0):

```
Function *f;
if (//some condition)
    *f = new Polynomial();
```

should at least give a warning because `f` is used (by the dereferencing operator) uninitialized, and should actually be a typecheck error since `new Polynomial()` has type `Function*` -it is a pointer- but `*f` has type `Function&`. You mean

```
Function* f;
if (somecondition)
    f = new Polynomial();
```

Please compile with all warnings and debug info, i.e. `g++ -Wall -Wextra -g`. Then learn how to use the `gdb` debugger and the [valgrind](http://valgrind.org/) memory leak detector.

Comment: I did that (I'll change it in the post also) but I am still getting a SegFault. I will try compiling as you suggests and see what the output is.

Comment: You need to use `gdb`; perhaps you want to use its `backtrace`, `break`, `display`, `watch`, `print` commands.

Comment: @rst6391 What was the actual fix? You modified your example to fix the apparent compile-time type errors.

Comment: @Jeff Yeah it was actually a typo. I am trying to debug using gdb, if that will not help I will try a different pattern.

Comment: @rst6391 If your actual code compiles and follows the pattern you now have above, just compile with `g++ -ggdb3 ...`, run it in gdb, and catch the segfault. If the segfault hits at the level of `main()`, just `print f` to see the pointer's value. IMO it's highly likely you never initialized it due to a logic error in your sequence of tests. Also, accepting an answer that you state in comments was not the actual source of the error is confusing for other readers.

Comment: @Jeff After quite a bit of debugging (of my actual code) I finally identified the source of the problem i.e. the if-statements' conditions were incorrect, resulting in an invalid pointer and the SegFault. Thanks for the support.

Comment: @rst6391 Glad I could help. Please consider upvoting and accepting my answer if you found it to be the correct one.